# Display Product Name in other table using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am here asking again for your help.

I want to group the Branch Product with the Quantity however, I have trouble displaying the product name as the product name. as of now I it display the product id not the product name

```
   +-----------------+   +-----------------+    +----------------+ 
  |  product table  |   | quantity table  |    |  branch table  |
  +-----------------+   +-----------------+    +----------------+
  |   id            |   |  prod_id      |    |   id           |
  |   productname   |   |  branch_id       |    |   branchname   |
  +-----------------+   |  quantity       |    +----------------+
                        +-----------------+
```

Branch model

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Quantity', 'branch_id');
    }
```

Quantity Model

```
public function branch()
    {
        return $this->belongsTO('App\Branch', 'branch_id', 'id');
    }
```

Product Model

```
public function productquantities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Quantity','prod_id');
    }
```

My view

```
@foreach($dataBranch as $Branch)
            <h1>Branch {{$Branch->branch_name}}</h1>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>  </th>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  @forelse($Branch->products as $Product)
                  <tr>
                  <td align="center" style="text-align:center"> <a href="#" class="avatar"><img src="{{ asset('productimg') }}/" width="100px"/> </a> </td>
                    <td> <a class="name">{{$Product->prod_id}} //this should be the product name instead of product id</a></td>
                    <td><em class="productprice">{{$Product->quantity}}</em>  </td>

                   </tr>
                   @empty
                   <tr><td colspan='4'><em>No Data</em></td></tr>
                  @endforelse


                </tbody>
              </table>
            @endforeach
```

my controller

```
  $dataBranch = Branch::with('products')->get();

enter code here
```

Comment: Why does your relation to the table `quantity` has the name `products`?

Comment: No @FelippeDuarte the quantity table has the productid and the branch id.. now I want to display the branch products with the product name on it..

Answer (score 0):

As of right now you are joining the branch with the quantities table and NOT the product table.  You can do something like below in your Branch model (untested).  The idea is a join through Quantity from Branch to Products.

```
public function productsThroughQuantity() {
    // The columns need to be added
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Products', 'App\Quantity', <columns>);
}
```

However, a problem that I can see, is if you do it this way, you may get an SQL warning about ambiguous columns in regards to branch and product id fields.  I would rename in your products table id => product_id and in your branch table id => branch_id.  In your quantity table rename branch_id to something like branch_table_id.

Then in your Branch and Product models:

```
protected $primaryKey = "<branch/products>_id";
```

Comment: yes. that is what my code does. I am joining the result of the quantity of the product and however the product name is on the product table. I cannot display it as i need a query to the product table

Comment: $dataBranch does not contain any columns from the products table.  Can you show me where the code you use to join the results of the products and the $dataBranch results?